# Is it safe to compact a CouchDB database that has continuous replication?

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

We have a couple of production couchdb databases that have blown out to 30GB and need to be compacted. These are used by a 24/7 operations website and are replicated with another server using continuous replication.

From tests I've done it'll take about 3 mins to compact these databases.

Is it safe to compact one side of the replication while the production site and replication are still running?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly safe.

Compaction works by constructing the new compacted state in memory, then writing that new state to a new database file and updating pointers. This is because CouchDB has a very firm rule that the internals of the database file never gets updated, only appended to with an fsync. This is why you can rudely kill CouchDB's processes and it doesn't have to recover or rebuild the database like you would in other solutions.

This means that you need extra disk space available to re-write the file. So, trying to compact a CouchDB database to prevent full disk warnings is usually a non-starter.

Also, replication uses the internal representation of sequence trees (b+trees). The replicator is **not** streaming the entire database file from disk onto the network pipe.

Lastly, there will of course be an increase in system resource utilization. However, your tests should have shown you roughly how much this costs on your system vs an idle CouchDB, which you can use to determine how closely you're pushing your system to the breaking point.

Answer (score 3):

I have been working with `CouchDB` since a while; replicating databases and writing `Views` to fetch data.

**I have seen its replication behavior and observed this, which can answer your question:**

1. In the replication process previous revisions of the documents are not replicated to the destination, only current revision is replicated.
2. Compacting database only removes the previous revisions. So it will not cause any problem.
3. Compaction will be done on the database on which you are currently logged in. So it should not affect its replica which is continuously listening for changes in it. Because it listens for the current revision changes not the previous revisions. To verify it you can see this:

Firing this query will show you changes of all the sequences of database. It only works on the basis of latest revision changes not the previous ones(So I think compaction will not make any harm):

```
curl -X GET $HOST/db/_changes
```

The result is simple:

```
{"results":[

],
"last_seq":0}
```

More info can be found here: [CouchDB Replication Basics](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/replication.html)

This might help you to understand it. In short answer of your question is **YES**, It is safe to compact database in continuous replication.

Comment: Your statement "In the replication process previous revisions of the documents are not replicated to the destination, only current revision is replicated" isn't quite right. All the edges of the revision tree that the destination has not seen yet are replicated as well as metadata about non-edge revisions that the destination has not seen. The winning revision - what you call the current revision - is the one with the longest branch in the tree (ie., when you resolve a conflict you are doing another write to make that branch longer).

Comment: Also, your second point "Compacting [the] database only removes the previous revisions" needs a bit more detail. Non-edge revisions have their bodies (the document) removed, but the headers are still there so that the full sequence tree can be re-built despite compaction. This is also true for deleted documents; a deletion is just another doc write with some special flags.

Comment: But in practice, I have seen that replicated database will not have any "previous revision" button enable because it does not have it. And   the size of the replicated database will be less than the original one because it does not replicated revisions. This is what I have seen in practice. If someone wants to replicate revisions then he will have to do a little effort tweaking existing default settings of replicator.

Comment: @SamBisbee I gave my answer so that the person who asked should understand it. I would have included abstracted details but those will not be worthy of it. This time what we do need to clear is about the issues in replication(in sync), if any? And I have also included sequence check query which will help in getting the changes in latest seq of database.